# Calling native code through the Android NDK crashes with Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) when called from non UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk

I am calling into my native C library using the NDK from my Activity. When calling from the main UI thread everything works fine (but the UI is blocked). When calling from a new thread (either created with `new Thread()` or using `AsyncTask`) it crashes with a "*A/libc(32044): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x77f1a000 (code=2), thread 32624 (Thread-56564)*" error in logcat.

I make two calls in the library. The first call executes ok. The second call crashes on the GetByteArrayRegion statement:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_library_process_data(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray jBuffer) {
    int len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jBuffer);
    unsigned char buffer[len];
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, jBuffer, 0, len, buffer);   // crash
    process_buffer(buffer);
}
```

The reason I am trying to run in a separate thread is to not block the UI during execution and to show a progress bar.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there any chance that the 2 calls overlap? meaning that the JNI method is being called by 2 threads at the same time? Also, please post the code for GetByteArrayRegion.

Comment: No, the calls are sequential. First a call to create a new file on disk, then a call to add data to it (which will be called more than once, also sequential).
I have no code for GetByteArrayRegion, it is defined in jni.h

Comment: Is it just me, or does that declaration of the buffer[] variable not make sense since it's a local stack variable being initialized at run time? Try changing it to buffer = malloc(len), then free(buffer) when finished.

Comment: It wasn't just you, you've actually solved my problem!
I wonder why this worked at all then.

Comment: Perhaps share your solution as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BitBank pointed out correctly, the declaration of buffer[len] does not allocate the memory and unallocated memory is used for the buffer (probably on the stack). This only became visible to me when using a different thread.
Changing it to

```
unsigned char *buffer;
buffer = malloc(len);
(*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, jBuffer, 0, len, buffer);
process_buffer(buffer);
free(buffer);
```

solved the issue.